# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1492)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm getting an exception in my vb.net project:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1492): You cannot paste this selection into a table. at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.Paste()

The code is:

```
bookmark.Select()
_WordApplication.ActiveDocument.SetCompatibilityMode(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2013)
_WordApplication.Selection.Copy()
_WordApplication.Selection.MoveStart()
_WordApplication.Selection.MoveUp(Unit:=Word.WdUnits.wdLine, Count:=1)
_WordApplication.Selection.Range.Paste()
_WordApplication.Selection.Paste()
```

This code works in some WIN7/WIN10-environments but not in all. Word version is 2013.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You're going to need to perform some debugging comparing all the details in cases that work and cases that don't. Eg. checking what differences are there is the selection you create. This would allow you to reach a point where you can re-create the issue at will.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what the selection contains. Most likely, it's something that isn't able to hold the content being pasted. Since you say "...into a table" I'm guessing a table structure is selected, such as end-of-cell or end-of-row. You'll find working with `Range` objects instead of selection more reliable and predictable. See this SO Q&A, for example, where the code in the Answer demonstrates how to get a Table range, a specific cell, and put the focus *in* the cell.

Comment: Bookmark is a table in word-template.  The idea is to read values from SQL-database and insert several rows to table in word-document.   
I have tried with different versions of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll with no success.